# Filter qry to get data according to Another Table

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart-3

This is query to get all categories available in database.

```
$sql = "SELECT cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY cp.level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS name, c1.parent_id, c1.sort_order 
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c1 ON (cp.category_id = c1.category_id) 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c2 ON (cp.path_id = c2.category_id) 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id) 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd2 ON (cp.category_id = cd2.category_id) 
    WHERE cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND 
    cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

to get this output [image]

> So, i am trying to get only that categories listed in
> ***rma_mapping_category***(this has category_id column)

so i tried this, but syntax got wrong by adding this(*AND rma_mapping_category rma*)...     /////////////////////

```
$sqs = "SELECT cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY cp.level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS name, c1.parent_id, c1.sort_order 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp AND rma_mapping_category rma
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c1 ON (cp.category_id = c1.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c2 ON (cp.path_id = c2.category_id) 
  ->    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c3 ON (rma.categoryid = c3.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd2 ON (cp.category_id = cd2.category_id) 
        WHERE cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND 
        cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

Also tried this...    ////////////////////// by this i am getting all categories rather than just ***rma_mapping_category***

Same result as First Query.

```
$sqs = "SELECT cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY cp.level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS name, c1.parent_id, c1.sort_order 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c1 ON (cp.category_id = c1.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c2 ON (cp.path_id = c2.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN rma_mapping_category rma ON (cp.category_id = rma.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd2 ON (cp.category_id = cd2.category_id) 
        WHERE cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND 
        cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

Any suggestion, what i sould try? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query worked as expected after adding ==

`INNER JOIN rma_mapping_category rma ON (cp.category_id = rma.category_id)` like below

```
    $sql = "SELECT cp.category_id AS category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY cp.level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS name, c1.parent_id, rma.type_id, c1.sort_order 
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c1 ON (cp.category_id = c1.category_id) 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c2 ON (cp.path_id = c2.category_id) 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id) 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd2 ON (cp.category_id = cd2.category_id)
    INNER JOIN rma_mapping_category rma ON (cp.category_id = rma.category_id) 
    WHERE cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND 
    cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a recursive query.

An example: to get all child categories that fall under category_id 20, I'd use the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (category_id, path_id) AS (
  SELECT     category_id,
             path_id
  FROM       oc_category
  WHERE      path_id = 20
  UNION ALL
  SELECT     c.category_id,
             c.path_id
  FROM       oc_category c
  INNER JOIN cte
          ON c.path_id = cte.path_id
)
SELECT * FROM cte JOIN `oc_category_description` cd ON cd.category_id = cte.category_id;
```

The [with](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) keyword is what does the magic. Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query#answer-33737203) answer to another question that helped me solve this issue in the past.

Comment: Thanks daniel, but query worked by adding "INNER JOIN rma_mapping_category rma ON (cp.category_id = rma.category_id) ".

Comment: btw, which query will execute faster acc. to you?

Comment: @Anmolsingh I've updated the answer to add the descriptions. In terms of speed, its not the quickest solution to create a temporary table at all. A clean select statement would be quicker however the challenge is that the query approach you had didn't work well and potentially would exclude sub-sub-sub categories. So there's a trade off to consider. How often is this query being executed?